# Why is a pressure type sensor fire warning system not affected by bends or kinks in the line?

Tags: sensors, fire

In a pressure based fire warning sensor, there is a line containing helium gas with a hydrogen core. Flight manuals say that a bend or kink in the gas line does not affect their operation. But if there is a bend and kink in the line that is severe enough, wouldn't that prevent expanding gas further down the line from making it through the twisted part and activating the responder assembly?

Answer (score 4):

It would take what amounts to a fold or crimp that provides a 100% gas seal. You'd have to fold the loop over and squeeze it together with pliers, and even then you might not get a complete gas seal.

Just bends and even kinks (sharp bends but not folds) from handling, or bumping into the sensor loop while working on it, can't create that kind of gas tight blockage.